# How to find a XML child element which has a default namespace in Python？

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

My goal is to find the XML child element which has a default name.

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<all:config xmlns:all="urn:base:1.0">
    <interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf-interfaces">
        <interface>
          <name>eth0</name>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <ipv4 xmlns="urn:b-ip">
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </ipv4>
          <tagging xmlns="urn:b:interfaces:1.0">true</tagging>
          <mac xmlns="urn:b:interfaces:1.0">00:00:10:00:00:11</mac>
        </interface>
  </interfaces>
</all:config>
```

I want to find the following element:

```
<mac xmlns="urn:b:interfaces:1.0">00:00:10:00:00:11</mac>
```

and change mac's text.

I have the following questions:

1. What is the xpath of mac?
2. How can I find "mac" using xpath since it has the default namespace?

My code does not work:

```
def set_element_value(file_name, element, new_value, order):
    filename = file_name
    tree = etree.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    xml_string = etree.tostring(tree).decode('utf-8')
    my_own_namespace_mapping = {'prefix': 'urn:b:interfaces:1.0'}
    myele = root.xpath('.//prefix:mac', namespaces=my_own_namespace_mapping)
    myele[0].text = "aaa"
    for ele in root.xpath('.//prefix:mac', namespaces=my_own_namespace_mapping):
        if count_order == order:
            ele.text = str(new_value)
        count_order += 1
def main():
    filename ="./template/b.xml"
    element = ".//interfaces/interface/mac"
    new_value = "10"
    order = 0
    set_element_value(filename, element, new_value, order)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to dig out in the stackoverflow, but no similar answer.

Could you please give me some tips?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be a little too complicated than necessary. Try the following to get to the mac address:

```
ns = {"x":"urn:b:interfaces:1.0"}
root.xpath('//x:mac/text()',namespaces=ns)[0]
```

or if you don't want to deal with namespaces:

```
root.xpath('//*[local-name()="mac"]/text()')[0]
```

Output in either case is

```
00:00:10:00:00:11
```

Comment: Yes! Your methods work well! Really great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Jack's methods, I fixed this issue:

The new code:

```
def set_element_value(file_name, element, new_value, order):
    filename = file_name
    tree = etree.parse(filename)
    tag_list = tree.xpath('.//*[local-name()="mac"]')
    print("tag:", tag_list, " and tag value:", tag_list[0].text)
    tag_list[0].text = "10"
    xml_string = etree.tostring(tree).decode('utf-8')
    print(xml_string)

def main():
    filename ="./template/b.xml"
    element = "mac"
    new_value = "10"
    order = 1
    set_element_value(filename, element, new_value, order)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
tag: [<Element {urn:ietf-interfaces}mac at 0x298fc4b69c0>]  and tag value: 10
<all:config xmlns:all="urn:base:1.0">
    <interfaces xmlns="urn:ietf-interfaces">
        <interface>
          <name>eth0</name>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <ipv4 xmlns="urn:b-ip">
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </ipv4>
          <tagging xmlns="urn:b:interfaces:1.0">true</tagging>
          <mac xmln="urn:b:interfaces:1.0">10</mac>
        </interface>
  </interfaces>
</all:config>
```